# How to paste locale automatically in routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Can I paste the default locale or locale from the session[:lang] as locale param when I type:

```
domain.com/feed => domain.com/:locale/feed
```

Now when I type `domain.com/feed` it prints the next locale error:

```
"feed" is not a valid locale
```

in the

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

How can I redirect automatically? Can I?

Comment: http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-routes-tricks-with-locales please see this link it will helps you.

Comment: @MKumar thanks! It works, but it(`get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false`)
 conflicts with the: `get '/:locale/', to: "home#index"`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade try what I asked..

Answer (score 0):

You can make it optional:

```
domain.com/feed => domain.com/(:locale/)feed, 
                   constraints: { locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ }
```

Read [3.2 Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments).